# Converting many PNGs to PDF?

Tags: pdf, conversion, imagemagick, png

I have been using the following command:

```
convert *.png out.pdf
```

But it seems to be limited to only convert 38 images, the output file is about 50 MB, it makes me wonder if there is a limitation in size or number of images.

I tried to renaming to 00.png, 01.png, ... , that did not help. I used `--verbose` no error is shown.

Comment: /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml , https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit

Comment: I increased memory and map, and it work out perfectly - thank you.