# png images to single pdf

Tags: shell, pdf, images, imagemagick

I have `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101` on Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried `convert *.png out.pdf` to convert 70 png files into a pdf, but strangely always only 18 pages in the pdf file. I didn't find any info from the help doc.

I also tried `img2pdf` but it support `jpg` only, not `png`.

There is a [related topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559324/converting-many-pngs-to-pdf) linked to [imagemagick doc](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit), but I tried
`convert -limit memory 8GiB -limit map 16GiB ....`
Also does not work.

Is there any solution for converting dozens png images to a pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You might have discovered a bug in imagemagick, if so report it.
- I would first convert each file and then merge the pdfs.
  You can then also create a file with multiple images per page using pdfnup.

Something like

```bash
#!/bin/csh
foreach file (*.png)
    set fileout = $file:r.pdf
    echo $file
    convert $file $fileout
end
pdfmerge *pdf
```